# Get a pop up text note when opening a tab file

Tags: mapinfo, tab

I know this is possible as I have done it before but I need a text note (pop up) to open when a tab file is opened. I know it's a simple one-line in the .tab file but just can't recall what the line is and can't find any info on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whereas @rossnixon's answer produces message in the message box, maybe the most direct way of popping up a message is to use `Note` keyword in a TAB file just before the **Definition Table**. For example `Note("Hello,"+Chr$(10)+"This is a popup...")` will yield a pop-up with the indicated message.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one that I use. You can reduce that to two lines.
(One 'set' line. One 'print' line).

```
  Set Window Message
      Font ("Franklin Gothic Medium Cond", 0, 8, 0, 65280 ) 
      Position (20, 10)
      Width 50.0
      Height 2.0

  print chr$(12)
  print "  This is where you put the pop-up message"
  print " "
```

Comment: I just tried this, it should be noted that the above code should go before the table definition.

Answer (score 1):

With the new 64 bit versions of MapInfo Pro, we have added a number of new events.
One of these is the TableOpened event.

If you create a MapBasic application and sign up for this event, you can show a note, a print message or even use the new Notification window to show a message for any table opened.

Of course it does require that your tool is running.